# RSA public key, PEM_write_RSAPublicKey, and rsautl compatibility

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I created a key-pair using the `RSA_generate_key() API` and wrote the public key to a file using `PEM_write_RSAPublicKey() API`.

When I use the the following `openssl` command to encrypt data,

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pkcs -inkey pubkey.pem -pubin -in encme.data > 
encrytedyou.data
```

I get,

> Unable to load public key.

However, when I use the:-

```
RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len, encrypt, decrypt, keypair, 
RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)
```

The encrypted data get successfully decrypted.

How should I convert the public key to a format compatible with openssl?

Thanks

Comment: [Use OpenSSL RSA key with .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30491534/608639). It provides the code in C++ and shows you the formats. You will have to choose the one that works for you. Instead of `PEM_write_RSAPublicKey` or `PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey`, use `PEM_write_PUBKEY` or `PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use convert the RSA structure to EVP_PKEY in order to use PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY and it worked perfectly with openssl

Comment: This was probably causing the need for the different format: `-pubin`. If you look at the ASN.1/DER files created by `i2d_RSAPublicKey_bio` and `i2d_RSA_PUBKEY_bio`, the differences will become readily apparent. They are lost in the PEM encoding.

Comment: This ended up being your duplicate: [OpenSSL's rsautl cannot load public key created with PEM_write_RSAPublicKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547646/608639).