# Function is not generating proper openssl rsa keys

Tags: c, linux, openssl, rsa, key-generator

This is a c function I wrote to generate openssl rsa 4096 bit keys.

```
    bool rsa_gen_keys()
    {    
    int             ret = 0;
    RSA             *rsa = NULL;
    BIGNUM          *bignum = NULL;
    BIO             *bio_private = NULL;
    BIO             *bio_public = NULL;
    int              bits = 4096;

    unsigned long k = RSA_F4;

    bignum = BN_new();
    ret = BN_set_word(bignum,k);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto cleanup;
    }

    rsa = RSA_new();
    ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, bits, bignum, NULL);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // write rsa private key to file
    bio_private = BIO_new_file("private_new.pem", "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio_private, rsa, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_flush(bio_private);
    // write rsa public key to file
    bio_public = BIO_new_file("public_new.pem", "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bio_public, rsa);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto cleanup;
    }    
    BIO_flush(bio_public);
cleanup:
    BIO_free_all(bio_private);
    BIO_free_all(bio_public);
    RSA_free(rsa);
    BN_free(bignum);
    return ret;
}
```

The keys generated by the above function seem to be missing something. When I try to use the public_new.pem file in another program, I get the following error:

```
140286309791384:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: PUBLIC KEY
```

However, if I use the openssl command to generate the key files, the files work fine.

```
$openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
```

I noticed the key sizes generated from the function and from the command line don't match. This is a clue, but what do I need to change in my function to fix this?

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 3272 Feb  6 09:19 private_key.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1  800 Feb  6 09:20 public_key.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 3243 Feb  6 10:43 private_new.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1  775 Feb  6 10:43 public_new.pem
```

BTW, I tried the above with 2048 bits keys and I get the same result and same size mismatch

Comment: `c/c++ function` == Undefined behaviour. :P

Comment: What form or encoding do you want? You can see the different encodings at [Use OpenSSL RSA key with .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30475758/608639).

Answer (score 2):

`openssl genpkey` is using `PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey` (PKCS#8) instead of `PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey` (PKCS#1): https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/genpkey.c#L161-L164.

You don't show how you generated `public_key.pem`, but it was probably written with `PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY` (X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo) vs `PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey` (PKCS#1).

From a PEM armor perspective:

- PKCS#1 Public: BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY
- X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo: BEGIN PUBLIC KEY
- PKCS#1 Private: BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY
- PKCS#8: BEGIN PRIVATE KEY

Comment: That explains the difference. I may need to switch to using EVP calls to generate the correct format instead of direct RSA call .. like EVP_PKEY_keygen()?.

Comment: Yep. The `EVP_*` (envelope(d)) structure, and the relevant file formats are about "what kind of key is this" and "oh, here's the key".  Using the `RSA` direct APIs means you should already know what key type it is, so it leaves that out.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I needed to use the format of the keys for PKCS#8 and X.509. So I switched to EVP functions to generate them. Here is a very simplified version of the code I ended up using (no error checking):

```
bool rsa_gen_keys() {
    int ret = 0;
    BIO *bio_private = NULL;
    BIO *bio_public = NULL;
    int bits = 4096;

    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

    // Get the context
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
    if (!ctx)
        goto cleanup;

    // init keygen
    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0)
        goto cleanup;

    // set the bit size 
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, bits) <= 0)
    goto cleanup;

    /* Generate key */
    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) <= 0)
        goto cleanup;


    // write rsa private key to file
    bio_private = BIO_new_file("private_new.pem", "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(bio_private, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 1) {
        goto cleanup;
    }
    BIO_flush(bio_private);

    // write rsa public key to file
    bio_public = BIO_new_file("public_new.pem", "w+");

    //ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bio_public, rsa);
    ret = PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio_public, pkey);
    if (ret != 1) {
        goto cleanup;
    }
    BIO_flush(bio_public);


cleanup:
    if(bio_private) BIO_free_all(bio_private);
    if(bio_public) BIO_free_all(bio_public);
    if(pkey) EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

    return ret;
}
```